# How to move a rectangle in a JFrame using KeyListener?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

I'm trying to move a rectangle I've created (actually, I'm changing X and Y variables I've created) in a JFrame using a KeyListener. I'd like to state that I **do not** wish to use keybindings. I would like to use a KeyListener. That being said, I can't seem to find anything wrong with my logic here.

Frame (Main) class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings ("serial")
public class GameFrame extends JFrame
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Java Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize (1000, 600);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground (Color.WHITE);
        frame.getContentPane().add (new GamePaint());
        frame.addKeyListener (new GameController());
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
```

Paint class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

@SuppressWarnings ("serial")
public class GamePaint extends JComponent
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public void paintComponent (Graphics graphics)
    {
        super.paintComponent (graphics);
        graphics.setColor (Color.BLACK);
        graphics.fillRect (x, y, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class GameController implements KeyListener
{
    GamePaint paint = new GamePaint();

    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            paint.x--;
            paint.repaint();
        }
        else if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            paint.x++;
            paint.repaint();
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased (KeyEvent event) {}
    public void keyTyped (KeyEvent event) {}
}
```

Comment: 1) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  An MCVE would have only a single `public` class and include the others in the same source.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating multiple instances of `GamePaint`...

```
frame.getContentPane().add (new GamePaint());
```

And

```
public class GameController implements KeyListener
{
    GamePaint paint = new GamePaint();
```

So when you `GameController` controller tries to change the `x`/`y` positions of the rectangle, it's not interacting with the instance of `GamePaint` which is actually on the screen...

Instead, create a single instance of `GamePaint`, add this to the frame and pass a reference to the `GameController`

```
GamePaint gp = new GamePaint();
frame.getContentPane().add (gp);
frame.addKeyListener (new GameController(gp));
```

And update the `GameController`...

```
public class GameController implements KeyListener
{
    private GamePaint paint;
    public GameController(GamePaint paint) {
        this.paint = paint;
```

But this approach is bunch of weirdness...isn't `GamePaint` suppose to be receiving keyboard input and not the frame??

Instead, consider using the key bindings API, it solves so many other issues associated with `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Instead of the controller modifying the `x`/`y` properties directly, it should be calling a method on the `GamePaint` class (something like, `moveLeft`, `moveRight` etc...), this way `GamePaint` can make the decisions about what that means...

But, personally, I'd inject a model in there, which controlled the location of entities and which the `GamePaint` simply painted and the controller controlled...but that's me...

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I think I understand now. But could you help me with one more thing? What exactly does the third block of code you wrote do? It works, but what's the logic behind it? Other than creating a constructor...

Comment: The update to the `GameController` class or the black where the `GamePaint` instance is created?

Comment: The update to GameController where you create a constructor and call `this.paint = paint`.

Comment: `this` refers to "the instance of this class", `this.paint` references to the current instance of `GameController`'s `paint` variable.  You are assigning the reference of `paint` (from the parameter) to this instance of `GameController`'s `paint` variable...